# Writing Rasa chatbot test stories with buttons

Tags: testing, rasa

I have a Rasa chatbot (Version 3.3.0) where i want to write [test stories](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/testing-your-assistant/#writing-test-stories). Unfortunetly it's is not documented, how to test a button click.

For example, i have created an utterance like this:

```
utter_choose_food:
    - text: pizza or burger
      buttons:
          - title: pizza
            payload: /order{{"food":,"pizza"}}
          - title: burger
            payload: /order{{"food":,"burger"}}
```

I tested to write a user-step with title, but this make predictions for other intents then order. Using the payload gets me nowhere either.

How to write a test story for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support :/

I figured it out myself and add a pull request for the rasa documentation:
https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/pull/11766